# Razor Pages routing issue in ASP.NET Core MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 Identity. I am using anchor tag for login and register in layout partial

```html
<a class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
<a class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

which works fine  but the problem arises when I use the link in other MVC view like for example in Dashboard controller `Index` view

```html
<a id="external-account" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path">
    <div>Verify with @provider.DisplayName</div>
</a>
```

It generate wrong link address as

```
<a id="external-account" href="/Dashboard?returnUrl=%2FDashboard&amp;area=Identity&amp;page=%2FAccount%2FManage%2FExternalLogin">
 google</a>
```

which it should be

```
<a id="external-account" href="/Identity/%2FAccount/Manage/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=/Dashboard">google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in startup - you should something similar to below that specifies the login path - I think this is used to generate the path when the HTML elements are generated

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

Comment: I do not think this code is anything related to my question if it does please me understand it. as I did not find anything external logins option in it.

Comment: I think is related to the route table in asp.net core but I can not find anything related to my problem. If you have any suggestion

Comment: Search your project for "Dashboard" and see where this is set - there is likely some routing setup somewhere that sets this incorrect path

Comment: Thank you I solve myself I was a routing issue and also we need to send post request in a form, not a link(archer tag)

Comment: Well done - Get/Post - i still do that myself. thankfully using Bootstrap just change the anchor to a button